# Realistic Value for the Rotational Inertia of a Gate

Tags: angular-momentum, rotation, moment-of-inertia

Don't worry guys i won't ask how to calculate the moment of inertia of the gate. I already have, but i have no experience in real life engineering, so i would be thankfull if any of you could review my result.

The Door wieghs about 90 kg 
Has a length of 3000 mm 
a height of 1115 mm
and a width of 40 mm

I Calculated the Moment of Inertia on the hinges and the result was 227.5 kgm².
I added a Picture so you can get an idea of how the gate looks like.
[image: This is how it looks like]

Comment: The only ways to answer your question are either (a) search the internet for typical values, (b) perform an experiment, or (c) make a calculation. Which one of these are you asking us to do for you? You have already done (c) yourself so what are you asking? I suspect it is "check my calculation"?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13134/realistic-value-for-the-rotational-inertia-of-a-gate

Comment: i just thought that if here are some people who have more experience in this are than i have, they could judge if my result sounds plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your solution is correct.

As a **crude approximation** we can consider the door to be a *uniform plate* of mass $m=90\:\mathrm{kg}$ and length $L=3\:\mathrm{m}$.

The inertia moment *about the end vertical axis* is in that case given by:

$$I=\frac{mL^2}{3}$$
Which yields $I=270\:\mathrm{kgm^2}$.

That is several orders of magnitude higher than your number.

Comment: My calculator says $mL^2 / 3 = 90 \times 3^2/3 = 270\,\text{kg m}^2$, not 810. If the OP's units are a typo, that seems a reasonable approximation, considering the OP's gate has more mass in the center.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I also did the aproximation with a full cuboid and got something around 800 kgm², thence why i wasn't sure my posted result is right. After reading @alephzero 's comment i repeated it in peace and got the same result of 270kgm².
My result now sounds pretty logical to. And again thank you to both of you.